# Почему плохое качество интернет соединения при высоком уровне Wi-Fi сигнала от роутера?

Tags: wifi, маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

Недавно купил роутер Asus RT-N12VP на замену старенькому D-Link DIR-615, тот стал плохо в зал доставать последнее время, из за чего неудовлетворительное качество интернета.

Новый Роутер достает хорошо, 4-5 полосок сигнала Wi-Fi ноутбук показывает. По inSSIDer"у тоже нормальный уровень сигнала. Но вот качество интернета (при использовании в другой комнате через стену) стало наоборот еще хуже, пользоваться почти невозможно, очень долго думает. Хотя когда находишься недалеко от роутера, в одной комнате, то работает отлично.

Пробовал в настройках роутера и каналы менять и порог готовности к передаче с сигнальным интервалом, стало немного лучше но пользоваться все еще почти невозможно. Хоть старый DIR-615 ставь обратно.
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: даже если Вы поставите роутер с усилителем такой силы, что вороны будут падать жаренными, пролетая возле него, это не поможет, так как вайфай - это двустороння связь и соответственно, передатчик на ноуте должен соответственно иметь хороший усилитель/антену. В настройках асус роутера можно посмотреть уровень сигнала от ноута.

Comment: после прочтения комментария у меня вопрос возник: неужели в сотовых телефонах 2G передатчики на столько мощные что могут передавать сигнал за много км?(даже в очень старых телефонах) и зачем тогда такие огромные телефонные станции, если передатчик в телефоне способен выдавать такую же мощность(звучит абсурдно, но получается так)

Comment: а в 2G не требуются такие большие скорости. И в более древних телефонах как раз передатчики достаточно мощные. 

Но у @SmitchBlack может быть и другая проблема. После смены роутера поменялся канал. А на новом канале сидит много других роутеров. И скорость просядет по самое нельзя.  Или очень мощный уровень вайфайя просто глушит все

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо большое! Действительно, посмотрел в настройках Роутера , отклик от самого ноутбука очень низкий, почти нету. С телефона уже проверил, все комфортно, интернет работает в зале отлично. Странно конечно что ноутбук хуже передает на асус, чем на DIR-615, и слабее маленького айфона. Но что поделать, видимо придется один роутер ставить в режим повторителя чтобы доставал.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что антенна вайфая в роутере отошла